# Question about the relation between the adjoin and inverse of linear operator on Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis

I am teaching myself functional analysis from a CS background. I am clueless about the following exercise problem of *introductory functional analysis*. Any hint or help is appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $T: H \rightarrow H$ a bijective bounded linear operator whose inverse is bounded. Show that $(T^{*})^{-1}$ exists and

$$
(T^{*})^{-1} = (T^{-1})^{*}
$$

It is easy to show $T^{-1}$ exists, but I seem to not able to find any clue to find the relation between the $T^{-1}$ and $T^{*}$.

Comment: You have that $\left<x,y\right>=\left<T^{-1}Tx, y\right> = \left<Tx,(T^{-1})^*y\right>=\left<x,T^*(T^{-1})^*y\right>$ for all $x,y\in\mathcal{H}$.  What does this tell you about the relationship between $T^*$ and $(T^{-1})^*$?

Comment: Yeah, $T^{*}(T^{-1})^{*} = I$, and $(T^{*})^{-1} = (T^{-1})^{*}$, since $T$ is bijective, it has inverse. I always try to find some relationship through $<x, T^{*}y>$ or $<Tx, y>$, so I always get stuck! Thanks a lot! Could I mark the comment as a answer? Or I should use *Answer Your Question*.

Comment: I hadn't really considered the hint worthy of an answer, but if you feel it helped enough then I'll gladly post it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Since $T$ is a bounded bijective linear operator, you have the existence of $T, T^*, T^{-1}$ and $(T^{-1})^*$ (*why?*)

So then $\left< x, y\right> = \left<T^{-1}Tx, y\right> = \left<Tx, (T^{-1})^*y\right> = \left<x, T^*(T^{-1})^*)y\right>$, for all $x,y\in\mathcal{H}$.  What does this tell us about the relationship between $T^*$ and $(T^{-1})^*$?

> Further hint, inverses are unique.